# Using Integer in a Double after the Comma

Tags: c#, int, double

What i Exactly mean is that i want to Do it like 0,integer but i have no idea How to do it, Is there any way that I could do that? I really Need It to get Working, Have been Searching for the Past 30 Minutes with no Luck or anything similliar to what Im seeking.

```
double a = done / 10.ToString().Length;
zeros = Math.Floor(Math.Log10(a) + 1) - 6 ;
double prepared;    

double toAdd = done / 10;
if(zeros == 0)
{
    prepared = 0,zeroes;
}
```

Comment: You need to give us examples of what you want -- `"Do it like 0,integer"` means absolutely nothing to me

Comment: edited, i hope its more understandable

Comment: Its not that much more understandable honestly.  Speak in plain terms what you want the functionality to be.  Do you want to control the number of zeroes when displaying a double?

Comment: I have a Integer, which Determines how many Zeroes after the Comma should go, and Now i need to Figure out how to make this work so i can use the Integer after the Comma. so for Example zeroes = 3 so prepared = 0,zeroes which should output 0,000

Comment: @ArkadiuszBrzoza: That is either padding (up to a multiple of 3) or a format string that forces that. Neither idea is ideal and will propably break the moment you try to change the culture this is executed in. Would it not be easier to just have the last digit of the integer be at the last decimal place to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

so you want to divide by 10 and round to 1 or more decimals?

```
  using System;

  public class Sample {
     static void Main() {
        Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(3.44m, 1)); 
        Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(3.45m, 1)); 
        Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(3.46m, 1)); 
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(4.34m, 1)); 
        Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(4.35m, 1)); 
        Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(4.36m, 1)); 
     }
  }
  // The example displays the following output:
  //       3.4
  //       3.4
  //       3.5
  //       
  //       4.3
  //       4.4
  //       4.4
```

retrieve from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=netframework-4.7.2#Round3_Example